# Update de dados da tabela user do laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estou tentando realizar um update, é retornado o response json de sucesso, porém quando consulto no banco não está alterando os dados.

Tentei:

```
Route::put('alteraDadosPerfil/{id}', 'Auth\LoginController@alteraDadosPerfil');

function alteraDadosPerfil(Request $request, $id){

     User::findOrFail($id)->first()->fill($request->all())->save();
     return response()->json('Dados de perfil alterados com sucesso', 200);
}
```

Tem que realizar algum procedimento a mais para atualizar a tabela users gerada pelo laravel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você tem o `findOrFail()` não precisa do `first()`. E, ao invés de utilizar o `fill()`, utilize o método `update()`.

```
function alteraDadosPerfil(Request $request, $id){
    try{
        \DB::transaction(function() use($request){
            User::findOrFail($id)
                ->update($request->all());
        });
    } catch(\Exception $e){
        return response()->json([$e], 500) 
    }

    return response()->json(['Dados de perfil alterados com sucesso'], 200)
}
```